# ffmpeg/avconv taking an rtp dump or pcap of a stream as input

Tags: ffmpeg, wireshark, rtp, avconv

I'm trying to get ffmpeg (or avconv) to take some kind of file representing an rtp dump as the input source and output this to a video.

I can get this to work fine in scenarios where i specify something like `ffmpeg -i rtp://<ip_addr>:<port> <outputfile>` or `ffmpeg -i sdp.sdp <outputfile>` and then stream (using `rtpplay` from an `rtpdump`) to that address/port. However, i'd like to give the actual `rtpdump` itself as the input - or something representing the rtp or rtp payload that can be fed in as a file (instead of streamed).

Thus far any type of `rtpdump` i try and input to to ffmpeg doesn't seem to work (usually complaining about not being able to find codec parameters for payload types that i'm not actually using, making me question the format of the input file).

Does anybody know of a way to do this? I'm not so concerned about the input being an `rtpdump` per se, but something derivable from a `wireshark` pcap would be good.

Thanks